# Status of the analog of the Haar measure on quantum groups

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, quantum-groups, c-star-algebras, haar-measure

In (Masuda, Nakagami, Woronowicz)'s [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0309338), in the introduction, the authors mentioned the deficiency common to both their and (Kusterman, Vaes)'s [approach](https://perswww.kuleuven.be/~u0018768/artikels/phd.pdf) regarding the Haar state (or Haar measure analog). The deficiency is that they had to presuppose existence when one would expect to derive it. The existence can be proven for compact quantum groups, where a multiplicative unit is assumed.

My question: What is the current status on this? Has the existence of the Haar measure analog been derived or is it still an axiom? The papers are not that recent, so maybe they achieved it.

A bonus question: What about Haar systems for locally  compact quantum groupoids? are they an axiom?

Comment: I'm only a spectator of LCQG stuff, but my impression is that this is still open.

Comment: If is necessarily an axiom, what then? What would it mean? A revision of the topological Hopf structures in order to derive the existence would be needed? Or only "Haar Quantum groups" should be studied? I'm sorry for being so demanding.

Comment: Henrique, I'm afraid this is where I'd have to defer to an expert, but there are some people who would know and who are occasionally on MO

Comment: So let us hope this question shows up to them.

Comment: I edited your tags since qa.quantum algebra seems to be more for the algebraic side and really this question is aimed at people who know about Kustermans-Vaes / Woronowicz /etc

Comment: It's ok. I mentioned QA because of Arxiv's category.

Comment: As to my knowledge, it is open, and there is almost no activity in solving it.